# Why is my snake hook in sculpting mode so sharp instead of smooth legs?

Tags: sculpting

I am trying to create a couple of smooth little legs with Snake Hook in Sculpting mode. But for some reason when I do this I get really sharp shapes, as you can see in the first picture. Whereas I am looking to do something that is like the second picture.

I used a lot of the subdivision, so there is enough geometry to work with.

What's going on?

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First thing apply the scale in *Object* mode otherwise the effect will be stretched. Also, increase your mesh density: Select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to convert tris to quads, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with a *Levels* of 2, apply the modifier. Maybe enable the *Dyntopo* option to create additional topology when you'll create the protrusions (lower down the *Detail Size* to have a dense topology). Back to *Object* mode don't forget to smooth the shading.

[image]

Comment: That does not make a difference.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: File is uploaded

Comment: I've selected the Snake Hook tool, activated Dyntopo and it works

Comment: It is definitely a bit better, but it is by no means as smooth as that second picture.

Comment: It should be possible without the Dyntopo option. I try to follow along this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj499sk5Szg&t=371s     - he doesn't change anything, just works with 'regular' settings

Comment: Of course, it's just that Dyntopo won't stretch your topology, it will add topology. The difference between your object and his is that his object has a denser mesh, to add topology to your current mesh, first thing select all and Alt J to convert tris to quads, then give a Subdivision Surface modifier with a Level of 2, apply the modifier, sculpt. Also, again, don't forget to apply the scale